# Ellipsis Text showing on focus in firefox

Tags: css, firefox

Consider the following fiddle. 
http://jsfiddle.net/up99h3yc/1/

Its using

```
text-overflow: ellipsis;
white-space: nowrap;
```

To truncate the text overflow But when you click the text in firefox for some reason firefox (not chrome) wants to show me the rest of the word or extra text.

Steps:

1) Open http://jsfiddle.net/up99h3yc/1/

2) Click on the word "am" if it is selected it works.

3) Put cursor between the a and the m in am and notice it messes up the ...

Runnning osx yosemtite

This seems minor but looks a little worse in my table when there is padding and is inconsistent.

Is there any way to prevent this effect or is it a firefox bug?

Comment: Can't reproduce on Firefox 35.0.1 on OS X.

Comment: Can't reproduce in FF on Win7 either.

Comment: Not happening in FF 36.0

Comment: +1 for can't reproduce in Firefox. What version are you using? I've used ellipsis extensively and never had any issue with it in any browser.

Comment: I am on 35.0.1 running OSX. But what i just noticed is if you select the text it works but if you have the cursor on it it doesnt. Updating steps.

Comment: Hmm a asked a developer next to me and he has same setup and is not seeing it...Wierd

Comment: I am running OSX Yose FF 35.0.1, was not able to reproduce